# I installed Windows 10 with bootcamp on Imac and my imac partition is lost it file type

Tags: macos, mac, bootcamp, imac

I am having serious trouble here, i install windows 10 in my imac 2015 model
now i am not able to boot in Mac OS, i am upgraded to New os 13.

I tried Option key on start, did not work
I tired Commond+R did not work

Nothing work for Mac OS seems like my imac become windows PC

Comment: What options are displayed when you boot whilst holding Alt/Option?

Comment: Can you use the Option-⌘-R key combination to boot from the Internet? If so, can you open a Terminal window and post the output from the command `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`?

Comment: there is no command key working on boot time, i tried everything, it seems like on hard disk formate type is changed to windows.

Comment: I have use all mac commands on boot up but noting work